# How to display permission request with api 14

Tags: java, android, permissions, file-permissions

I need to display request permission (Read external storage) at run time. without the permission my app crash instantly.

Comment: Runtime permissions do not exist on API Level 14 devices. You simply request the permission in the manifest, as developers have done for a few years. If you are having problems using the `<uses-permission>` element, ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are requesting the permission, the complete Java stack trace of your crash, and the code that causes the crash.

Comment: You'd be more likely to get a useful answer on SO if you provide some code around the problem, more information about the error(s) and whether you've tried anything (to avoid duplication from any suggestions).

Answer (score 1):

In API 14 you don't need to do a request.

Just put in your manifest above `<application>` section:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Requesting permissions at run time is not supported with API level 14, it isn't supported until API level 23.

If you're running your app from Android Studio on a device or emulator where the app is already installed, your app will not ask for permission when it runs. If you inadvertently remove the permission you will need to manually grant the permission through the Application Manager on the device or emulator.

To prevent the initial crash, you could wrap the offending call in a permissions check.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                      == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // READ DATA
}
```

Hope this helps!